# Equivalent to readRawData from C++ in Python

Tags: python, file, byte, bytestream

In C ++ there is a `readRawData` function that helps to read the byte stream in a file. For example:

`stream->readRawData(layerName, 64);`

So I have 64 bytes to read the layer name. After these 64 bytes, I want to read the name:

`stream_name->readRawData(m_name, 4);`

And so on, without going backwards.
Is there anything similar in Python?

Comment: What let you think that Python `read` method on a byte stream is different?

Comment: `file = open(path, 'rb'); layer_name = file.read(64); m_name = file.read(4)`, however `read(n)` may return less than `n` bytes on EOF, you need to check `len(bytes)` of returned bytes; https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Where is `readRawData` defined? It’s not part of C++.